# Use a sequence of bernouli trials to find the possibility of an event happening

Tags: r, bernoulli-process

I have the data below and We have a game, that has a prize jackpot. The jackpot prize starts at 1,000 credits and every round you play the jackpot increases, until someone wins the jackpot and it resets back 1,000 credits.

To play a round you 'pay' 1 credit and the jackpot prize increases by 0.011382 (1.1383% of your 1 credit goes into the prize jackpot fund).

We have recorded the amounts the prize has been won at over the last few months.

The sample is small but we want to try to determine

Using the Bernoulli process (a sequence of Bernoulli Trials) to see the chance of the prize going over 25,000 credits. How can I do this in R? Does the whole thought makes sense?
prize_amounts <- c(
3270.35, 3547.73, 3616.09, 4171.12, 2991.38, 4173.81, 1798.59, 7232.75, 5054.53,
6476.27, 8259.84, 3932.46, 4346.68, 11433.26, 4850.1, 2905.25, 8174.9, 9307.45, 5737.27,
4434.69, 7542.42, 8627.02, 7273.14, 9326.01, 9129.27, 7135.21, 3577.68, 10711.62,
8933.94, 4224.24, 9283.57, 7467.65, 4977.56, 3526.48, 5248.06, 7831.2, 7333.13, 4839.57,
8714.5, 8631.6, 1716.21, 5201.42, 7358.18, 9427.66, 1766.16, 9027.67, 5838.49, 6729.6,
7872.61, 6003.57, 3389.34, 5542.54, 8265.95, 2364.84, 6586.25
)

```
# Define the parameters
initial_prize = 1000
rounds = 0
target_prize = 25000
simulations = 10000  # Number of simulations to run

# Function to simulate a single game
simulate_game <- function() {
  prize = initial_prize
  while (prize <= target_prize) {
    prize = prize + 0.011382  # Increase the prize by 1.1383% each round
    rounds = rounds + 1
  }
  return(rounds)
}

# Simulate multiple games
results <- replicate(simulations, simulate_game())

# Calculate the probability of reaching the target prize
probability <- sum(results <= 1000) / simulations  # 1000 rounds as an arbitrary upper limit

# Print the probability
cat("Probability of reaching 25,000 credits or more in", simulations, "simulations:", probability, "\n")
```